# Home key not working in terminal

Tags: command-line, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

I am using GNOME Terminal 2.7.3 and zsh 4.3.9 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

`Home` and `End` are not working. Nothing happens and nothing gets displayed when I press them. but they work when I press `shift + Home` (Scrolls to the beginning of shell output.) and also work in other GUI programs.
I googled and tried the following. No change :(

```
  885  bindkey "\e[1~" beginning-of-line
  886  bindkey "\e[H" beginning-of-line
  887  bindkey "\e1~" beginning-of-line
  888  bindkey "\eH" beginning-of-line
  889  bindkey "\e[0H" beginning-of-line
```

PS: When I am in the last tab and press `Ctrl + pagedown` I get `;5~` printed on the screen. Does that give any clue?

Comment: Do you have a `.inputrc` in your home directory? Does this happen with a freshly created user? Did this always happen, or did it start one day?

Comment: No I don't have `.inputrc`. I don't permission to create new user. This was always like that. I'am living with `ctrl +a` and `ctrl+e`.

Comment: I guess in that case I won't suggest `ctrl+a` & `ctrl+e` ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape sequences sent by function and cursor keys consist of an escape character followed by printable characters. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Home</kbd>. This will insert the escape sequence literally. Then add a `bindkey` instruction to your `~/.zshrc`.

The instruction is likely to be (note `O`, not `0`):

```
bindkey '\e[OH' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[OF' end-of-line
```

Comment: nothing gets printed when I press Ctrl then Home. Nothing happens. Tried changing 0 to O as well.

Comment: @balki It's Ctrl+V, not Ctrl. I just realized there was a formatting problem in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! :) I am now used to `ctrl + a` and `ctrl +e` and vi mode

Answer (score 9):

I found I had to hit `CTRL-v`, let go, then the `Home` or `End` key to get the sequences `^[[H` and `^[[F` for `Home` and `End` respectively. Adding the following lines to the `.zshrc` file solved the problem for me:

```
bindkey '^[[H' beginning-of-line
bindkey '^[[F' end-of-line
```

Comment: I had this problem but only in IRB ruby shells, not in ZSH shells. To fix, I added `"\e[H":beginning-of-line` and `"\e[F":end-of-line` lines to `~/.inputrc`

Answer (score 7):

Add these lines to `/etc/zshrc` and then do a `source /etc/zshrc` (taken from [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2008/msg00794.html))

```
bindkey '\e[1~'   beginning-of-line  # Linux console
bindkey '\e[H'    beginning-of-line  # xterm
bindkey '\eOH'    beginning-of-line  # gnome-terminal
bindkey '\e[2~'   overwrite-mode     # Linux console, xterm, gnome-terminal
bindkey '\e[3~'   delete-char        # Linux console, xterm, gnome-terminal
bindkey '\e[4~'   end-of-line        # Linux console
bindkey '\e[F'    end-of-line        # xterm
bindkey '\eOF'    end-of-line        # gnome-terminal
```

Comment: This worked for me where the accepted answer did not.

Comment: @WadeWilliams welcome to stack exchange

Answer (score 6):

I'm on fedora now yet I suggest you to read Archlinux's wiki *carefully*, all of it: [Home and End keys not working](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Home_and_End_keys_not_working).

What I did to fix it:

1. Press Ctrl-V Home, the escaped sequence for Home key is printed. It is **not** `\e[4~` and `\e[1~` as I expected to be by looking at `/etc/inputrc`. It was `[H` and `[F`
2. Extract the terminal info `infocmp $TERM >terminfo.src`
3. Open that file for editing, such as `vim terminfo.src`, look for `khome` and `kend` it's assigned to something, let's say `khome=\E[1~` and `kend=\E[4~` which is not working in this case. remove it and replace it with the sequence you found in step #1, so for me, after editing it was: `khome=\E[H` and `kend=\E[F`.
4. If you want to play it safe make sure `[F` and `[H` (or whatever sequence you just used) is not assigned to something else or things will be messed up!
5. run `tic terminfo.src` which creates `~/.terminfo` directory.
6. On top of `.zshrc` before any and all other commands, put: `export TERMINFO=~/.terminfo`

Open a new terminal window and you should be fine, home and end must be working now.

P.S: The bindkey method should theoretically work and is easier, but it didn't for me.

Comment: Also tested in CentOS + _bash_ - works! Thank you :)

Comment: +1: it was mentioned in the link, but i was unaware that if doing ctrl-v gave me `^[[H` that you should replace the `^[` with `\e` to get `\e[H`

Comment: So now it wont work in terminals that properly emulate xterm? Or does he have a broken terminfo?

Answer (score 6):

This answer explained my problem really good and fixed it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/686458/5472892

**TL;DR:** Change your PuTTY terminal type from default `xterm` to `linux`.

Maybe someone can use it too.